# How to open a site using Terminal(Mac) in which username and password is required?

Tags: macos

I am using open command in my Mac terminal to launch a website through default browser which is Mozilla firefox , but that site after opening immediately requires username and password and I don't know how to give it . Kindly help me in this issue

Answer (score 1):

`firefox http://username:password@somesite.com`

Note that this will make your username and password public to anyone who runs `ps aux` on your system (nb, is it ps -ef on osX?)

Comment: this is working but for the site , I have to give master password too . How can i do that

Comment: What do you mean master password? Is it HTTP basic auth, or a form?

Comment: then that should work. Can you elaborate on what's not working?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Selenium might be of any interest to you, too. You can create scripts and it will follow your scripts in the browser.

E.g. login, click....
There is a firefox plugin, which lets you record a 'macro'. Later on you can replay it.

Search on stackoverflow for more infos on selenium or check out the firefox plugin:

http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/

Greetings,

Jan

Answer (score 0):

You're probably going to get better resulting using Apple Script to control the Firefox application.

Comment: After logging in , I need to download files under few links , is that possible too ?